# MySQL 5.7 - how to get include empty results in this join

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.7.

I have two tables `firms` and `firm_reviews`. I'd like to be able to select all the firms and the count of firm_reviews. If they have 0 reviews, I'd still like them to be part of the result set. I have:

```
select count(*) as review_count, fr.org_id, f.name from 
  firm_reviews fr right join firms f 
   on fr.org_id = f.org_id 
   group by org_id 
   order by review_count desc;
```

but this doesn't firms that don't have any firm_reviews. How would I be able to to do this?

##### Edit 1

Looks like something like this does it (thanks to comments):

```
select  f.org_id, f.name, count(fr.org_id) as review_count 
 from firms f left join firm_reviews fr 
 on f.org_id = fr.org_id group by f.org_id 
 order by review_count desc;
```

Comment: you need to use `count(fr.org_id)`. Otherwise you count the rows with no match as 1 instead of 0.

Comment: `group by org_id` should complain about the ambiguous column name. So this can't be your actual query. It has to be `group by f.org_id`.

Comment: If you used `group by fr.org_id`, all the firms with no reviews will be combined into a single group, because they all have `fr.org_id = NULL`

Comment: BTW, most SQL programmers prefer LEFT JOIN rather than RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: thx @Barmar  - I added what seems to do it; yeah, was editing out a few things. Feel free to add as answer if you want points.

Comment: The question is closed, answers can't be added.

Comment: I'm #11 in total reputation. I'm doing fine on points :)

Comment: you likely want to select (and group by) f.org_id